# Binding to LDAP server failed. The supplied credential is invalid

Tags: 2013, cme, ldap

We are not able to log into the Tridion CMS. This was working before.

We did Not do any config changes and License issues. All happened of sudden.

Below is more details.

> "System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault]: Binding to LDAP server '************' failed. The supplied credential is invalid. (Fault Detail is equal to Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault)."

Any clue may help to debug more on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the credentials that you are using to connect to the LDAP server are no longer valid; maybe the password expired or someone changed the password policy on the domain level.

I'd double-check your Directory Service configuration settings (e.g. "search account password") as well as the MTSUser account to make sure they are up-to-date and working.